# Web-Config настройки для отдельной страницы

Tags: asp.net

Здравствуйте!
Есть мастер пейдж, в head'е которого

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7"/>
```

В проекте есть 1 страница, контролы которой из-за этой строчки ведут себя неадекватно.
Можно ли применить следующее для 1 конкретной страницы, и как это сделать?
Знаю, что можно просто сделать веб-конфиг и воткнуть его в папку с данной страницей, но в этой папке есть еще и другие страницы + если в мастере в head'e есть этот мета тег, то тот параметр, что в веб-конфиге для моей папки, перекрывается и в итоге не работает.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <httpProtocol>
         <customHeaders>
            <clear />
            <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=EmulateIE7" />
         </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Что это за ернуда и зачем она нужна можно найти [здесь](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc817570.aspx)

Вопрос: Как применить параметр для отдельной страницы, не отменяя такой же параметр но с другим значением для всех остальных страниц?

Спасибо!

Добавлено: Догадался убрать из хеда и воткнуть в главный веб-конфиг, но тем не менее, вопрос про задание параметра для 1 конкретной страницы актуален.

**Решение:
Вернул все назад в хед мастера, и у нужной страницы в Page_load вставил**

```
HtmlMeta keywords = new HtmlMeta();
keywords.HttpEquiv = "X-UA-Compatible";
keywords.Content = "IE=8";
Page.Header.Controls.AddAt(0, keywords);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужен элемент [`location`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
<configuration>
  <location path="YourPage.aspx">
    <system.webServer>
      <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
          <clear />
          <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=EmulateIE7" />
        </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

таким образом можно переопределить настройки для конкретной страницы.

Comment: Спасибо
Решил проблему немного по другому)

Comment: По моему мнению, если настройки можно выставить в web.config'е, то  лучше этим воспользоваться:

 - во-первых, при необходиости
   изменений, не понадобиться изменять
   код приложения и заново его собирать.
 - во-вторых у вас будет возможность "на
   лету" включать/выключать это для
   всего приложения или отдельных
   страниц.